# Change the duration for the screenshot thumbnails

Tags: macos, mojave, screen-capture

macOs Mojave introduced screenshot thumbnails.

Is it possible to change the thumbnail duration? (The settings for the screenshot app do not provide this feature).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

You can change it using this command in Terminal. The 15 in the command would change it to a 15 second thumbnail preview duration.

`defaults write com.apple.screencaptureui "thumbnailExpiration" -float 15 && killall SystemUIServer`

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is to display a thumbnail of the image for a short delay before writing the image to the `Documents` folder. An alternative would be to set the `Clipboard` as the `Save to` in the Screenshot options. In this case, the image is placed in the clipboard instead of being written to a file. You can then paste the image. Here, no thumbnail is displayed, but the image in the clipboard can be viewed in the Finder. (From the Finder menu bar, select `Edit`➝`Show Clipboard`). If you need to drag and drop the image, then one method would be to set `Preview` as the `Save to` in the Screenshot options. From the Preview application menu bar, select `View`➝`Thumbnails` or the <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> key combination. You can drag and drop the thumbnail.

I realize your question was to increase the delay. This answer attempts to point out alternatives to having the image end up being saved to the `Documents` folder by default after the delay has expired.